# angularjs directive rendered by third party component is not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a simple angularjs directive that I use to show a tooltip.

```
<div tooltip-template="<div><h1>Yeah</h1><span>Awesome</span></div>">Click to show</div>
```

It works fine but now I'm trying to use it inside a timeline javascript component (visjs.org)

I can add items with html to this timeline like this

```
 item...
 item.content = "<div tooltip-template='<div><h1>Yeah</h1><span>Awesome</span></div>'>Click to show</div>";
 $scope.timelineData.items.add(item);
```

The item is well displayed on the page BUT the code of the tooltip-template directive is never reached.

I suspect that because a third party component is rendering the item, the dom element is not read by angular.

I've tried to do a $scope.$apply(), $rootScope.$apply but the result is the same. The directive is never reached.

How can I tell angular to read my dom to parse these directives ?

Here is the directive code :

```
.directive("tooltipTemplate", function ($compile) {
    var contentContainer;
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var template = attrs.tooltipTemplate;

            scope.hidden = true;

            var tooltipElement = angular.element("<div ng-hide='hidden'>");
            tooltipElement.append(template);

            element.parent().append(tooltipElement);
            element
              .on('click', function () { scope.hidden = !scope.hidden; scope.$digest(); })


            $compile(tooltipElement)(scope);
        }
    };

});
```

**Edit**

Added plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/lNPday452GiZJBhMH4Kl?p=preview

Comment: can you try wrapping `item.content = "<div tooltip-template='<div><h1>Yeah</h1><span>Awesome</span></div>'>Click to show</div>";` this inside a $timeout function?

Comment: One thing is certain, in order for Angular directives to go live, they have to be compiled. So the first thing to do is `var elem = $compile('<div tooltip....>')`. If the `item.content` can be a DOM object, then you are in luck; just do: `item.content = elem[0]`. Otherwise you will have to somehow compile the content *after* it has been added to the DOM by vis. For this case, using a tooltip library independent of Angular may be a better option.

Comment: @Divya no I cannot this is handled by the component.

Comment: @Nikos I added the code of my directive to explain better what it does but inside the directive I compile the code of the template. Again, the directive works fine outside of the timeline!

Comment: Yes inside the directive the template is compiled. What I mean is that the HTML string you give to vis.js is *not* compiled, so Angular does not have a chance to compile your directive; Angular knows nothing about that piece of DOM! That is why you (most probably) have to compile it manually. Unfortunately I do not know vis.js, so I cannot tell if it would accept a DOM element there. I would experiment a bit, if you could provide a fiddle/plunk.

Comment: Ok I understand! Thanks for your help Nikos I'm working on the plunker ^^

Comment: I have added plunker!

Comment: I also have the same problem for timeline, and as I dig deep into the visjs timeline, it only accepts template contents as raw html or html object which is instance of Element. And also it uses only native javascript dom manipulations, so I couldn't able to give the compiled html content from angular

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do the same thing and came with a solution by manually creating scope and compile'ng the html of the directive with the scope using `$compile` method. Below a snippet

I did the below part inside a directive that created the timeline . Using the scope of that directive ,

```
                var shiftScope = scope.$new(true);

                shiftScope.name = 'Shift Name'

                var shiftTemplate = $compile('<shift-details shift-name="name"></shift-details>')(shiftScope)[0];
```

I passed shiftTemplate as the content and it worked fine .

But trying to do this for >50 records created performance issues .